# Git filter-branch: possible to update commit messages to reference old commit IDs?

Tags: git

I can successfully run `git filter-branch` on some code to e.g. merge another repo into a subdirectory [1]:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '
  git ls-files -s |
  perl -pe "s{\t\"?}{$&helper/}" |
    GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info &&
  mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE
' remotes/helper/master
```

But now, I'd also love to expand each commit's message to include its former ID (SHA hash), since those commits may have had comments/conversation on GitHub which aren't getting transferred over.

E.g. add an extra line like this (where `bob/helpers` is hardcoded/known in advance):

```
[COPIED FROM bob/helpers@76c7c080b3bd2f93dc78e4864899d668a57cd9f9]
```

As far as I can tell, Git's `msg-filter` only gives me the original message, and Git's `env-filter` doesn't contain the commit ID (SHA has) as an input variable. Is this possible then, or no?

Thanks!

[1] Via [this great article](http://zrajm.org/ref/git-repo-merging.html), with the Perl filter from [this email thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Filter-branch-s-quot-move-tree-to-subdirectory-quot-example-fails-with-BSD-sed-td7466007.html) to workaround a bug on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--msg-filter` would be where to do it, and the original commit ID is in the environment variable `$GIT_COMMIT`, so (untested) make the message filter simply: `cat; echo "[COPIED FROM bob/helpers@$GIT_COMMIT]"`.

Comment: Works fantastically well! Didn't know that the environment variable was there. Thanks!